# jQuery doesn't work on items already processed

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#userID option').dblclick(function() {  
        return !$('#userID option:selected').remove().appendTo('#removeList');  
    });

    $('#removeList option').dblclick(function() {  
        return !$('#removeList option:selected').remove().appendTo('#userID');  
    });  
});
```

This works but the items that are transferred to the other list cannot be transferred back, but other items that were in the other list can be transferred back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate the event to the containers so that they are not statically linked on the element itself..

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#userID').on('dblclick','option', function() {  
        return !$(this).remove().appendTo('#removeList');  
    });

    $('#removeList').on('dblclick','option',function() {  
        return !$(this).remove().appendTo('#userID');  
    });  
});
```

(*i changed the inner selectors to `this`. But if you are moving multiple items at once you should use your original ones*)

(*you also do not need to `remove()` them first, just appending them to the other list, will remove them from the current one ie. `$(this).appendTo('#removeList')`*)

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/HAcv5/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you are using `remove` which removes the element from the DOM along with any event handlers attached to it. Try using `detach` instead:

```
$('#userID option').dblclick(function() {  
    return !$('#userID option:selected').detach().appendTo('#removeList');  
});

$('#removeList option').dblclick(function() {  
    return !$('#removeList option:selected').detach().appendTo('#userID');  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$('#userID option')` to bind events, you're binding them to those specific options -- so the option that was moved to the #removeList still has the `appendTo('#removeList') action attached to it.  The event is still working, it's just appending the item to the list it's already in.

Instead of attaching events to every individual item in the lists, you want to attach your events to the lists themselves; that way they'll continue to work even when the list contents change:

```
$('#userID').on('dblclick','option', function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#removeList');
};
```

(It's not necessary to remove() or detach() the option nodes before appending them elsewhere; reparenting a node implicitly removes it from the original location.)